# Unable to print background colors while writing to Excel

Tags: excel, perl

I am trying to generate a background color randomly and print the Excel 
field using that color. I put all the colors in an array and generated a 
random number to get an element randomly. This part is done but the 
"add_format( bg_color => $color ) isn't working as no color is printed 
 when using 'write' function with $format specified.

If i try a fixed value like 'add_format( bg_color => 'red' )' rather than 
a $color, then the excel is printed with red color. But the 'add_format( 
bg_color => "$color" ) doesn't seem to work.

```
  sub random_color_select {
      my @colors= ("blue","brown","cyan","gray", "green", "lime", "yellow") ;
      my $random = int(rand(10));          
      return "$colors[$random]\n";
   }

   sub print_excel {     
      my $color = &random_color_select();
      my $format = $workbook_mtr->add_format();
      my %hash1= ("bg_color" => "$color");
      $format->set_bg_color($hash1{bg_color});

      //No color is printed using below line               
      $worksheet->write("A${row_mem}", "mod", $format);
    }
```

Expect the output excel file to have different color each time run the 
 script but no color is printed as background.

Comment: Why does the output of `random_color_select` include a newline?

Comment: That was just used to print the $color more clearly. Removed it and tried again, didn't work.

Comment: if you always want a color, do `my $random = int(rand(@colors));`

Answer (score 1):

One of the issues with your code is:

```
$random = int(rand(10));
```

Unless you have 10 colours in the array, it will sometimes return a null value.
Much better to use the length of the array as @ysth commented.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use 5.014;

main();

sub main
{
    my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('background_colour_test.xls');
    my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

    ## get random colour 
    my $color = &random_color_select();
    say "Colour is ".$color;

    #  Add and define a format
    my $format = $workbook->add_format("bg_color" => $color);

    my $col = 0;
    my $row = 0;

    $worksheet->write($row, $col, 'Cell with Background color', $format);
    $row++;
    $worksheet->write($row, $col, 'Cell without background color');
}


sub random_color_select 
{
    my @colors= ("blue","brown","cyan","gray", "green", "lime", "yellow");
    my $random_color = int(rand(@colors));
    return $colors[$random_color];
}

exit;
```